# jsmpp sms delivery report and receiving

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I am using jsmpp library for sending sms with connection to remote sms center. I have 2  problems:

1) At first, when I send sms to any mobile number, even to switched off mobiles I get  DELIVERED status, but in real the mobile is turned off.

2) I can send messages to any mobile number and receive delivery reports for sent message using connection to sms center. But how can I receive sms sent to sms center via jsmpp? For example, I send sms from my mobile to any short number, how can I take this sms from sms center?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check with SMSC(providers) why they are sending  "DELIVERED" and for the second issue 
find the ReceiveSubmittedMessageExample.java ,MessageReceiverListenerImpl.java classes in jsmpp examples .

Answer (score 0):

actually deliver sent as response by the SMSC doesn't mean delivering the short message to the MS but to the MSC , and the MSC is responsible of delivering the SMS to the end user in the normal case of MO-MT  or AO-MT
the MSC can forward the SMS the MS and if this one doesn't acknowledge the MSC ,he resends the SMS but will not report this to SMSC.

thus the reponse you get from SMSC is normale nothing to worry about.